# "@android:drawable/ic_" vs "@*android:drawable/ic_"

Tags: android, resources

Does anybody know where I can find documentation on the asterisk? It appears to override the protection of 'private' variables in subclass android.R.drawable.

Comment: Where have you encountered the asterisk syntax? That does not look familiar. Thanks!

Comment: I found it in the menu resource for the mail app: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=res/menu/message_list_option.xml;h=dd9de911f22ae435b2fdaf6f6a79df3e48589f85;hb=master#l17

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The @*android is used to access private resources. These resources can change or be removed between two versions of Android so you should NEVER use them. This is for framework use only.

Comment: I agree, and besides I found all the resources in one place so I can easily copy them to my app. But my question is is it documented anywhere?

Comment: No it is not documented because it's a private API :)