# Can't access (some) native system resources (icons)

Tags: android, android-layout

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />`

Can't find some images in: `@android:drawable/` (for example ic_menu_login)

But when I navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-4\data\res\drawable` the images exist there (ic_menu_login.png)

**When:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Refresh"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/login" android:title="Log in"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_login></item>
</menu>
```

**I get error in console:**

W/ResourceType( 5524): Bad XML block: header size 191 or total size 12517572 is larger than data size 0

Project -> clean does not help.

This problem does not occur with every image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all Android resources are public, as they may be absent on some devices. Attempting to use them - such as `@android:drawable/ic_menu_login` - will result in an error message when you attempt to compile your app.

If you really want to a certain drawable found in the Android SDK, you should copy it (i.e. `ic_menu_login.png`) into your project.

Comment: Any reference to that statement?

Comment: From Romain Guy (android dev team): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886873/androiddrawable-ic-vs-androiddrawable-ic

Comment: Well public resources are declared in the `public.xml` file in the Android SDK. Here's the list of drawables: [public.xml](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/public.xml&type=cs&l=740) and [here's a web-based drawables explorer](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/)