# difference between @android and @*android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've been given a few xml layout files made by another group of developers, one thing concerns me is that they used a mix of `@android` and `@*android` in their files, like

```
@android:style/Theme

@*android:style/Theme
```

Their xml layout files seem to be working fine at the moment, but I am curious about the difference between @ and @*, please help!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886873/androiddrawable-ic-vs-androiddrawable-ic